# Creating a function to load and display a CSV in PHP

Tags: php, function, csv

I'm a beginner so sorry if my question is inappropriate.
I'm trying to create a function that allows me to load and display a csv file in PHP, but it keeps giving me an error.

Here is the function:

```
    <?php
function load_csv_file($nom){
    $tableau_asso= array();
    $fichier = fopen($nom, "r");
    while($ligne = fgetcsv($fichier, 1024, ';')){
        array_push($tableau_asso, $ligne);
    }
    fclose($fichier);
        foreach($tableau_asso as $ligne){
        print($ligne[0]);
        print(", ");
        print($ligne[1]);
        print("<br>");
    }

    return $tableau_asso;
}
?>
```

Then I created another document where I call this function:

```
<?php
include("library.php");
$nom = '‪C:\\MAMP\\htdocs\\MEDAS-PHP\\data.csv';
$mon_tableau = load_csv_file($nom);
?>
```

When I try to load it, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: I'm using MAMP and when I open the second file that calls the function I get this error on my navigator: "This page is not available for the moment."